# Imposible Iniciar sesión en login php

Tags: php, html, mysql, login

les comento que no he podido iniciar sesión en un sistema que recién subí a internet, no se si sea problema del servidor, ya que cuando estaba en local funciona muy bien puedo iniciar sesión sin problema, y a pesar que ingreso bien los datos, no me permite iniciar sesión.

Ya probé con diferentes versiones de php, la base de datos esta bien configurado no se a que se deba ese problema de no poder loguearse, les dejo parte del código del index y parte del código del otro modulo que redirige cuando se inicia sesión..

Les dejo el link del sistema http://ralj.edu.mx/tutorias/

**usuario**: admin

**pass**: 147258

```
<?php
    require("conexion/conexion.php");
    // Inicio de la sesión para su identificación
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){
        //en caso de que se detecte un inicio de sesión se redireccionará al menú del sistema
        header("location: extraescolares/home.php");
    }

    //modulo de inicio de sesión
    //en caso de que no se haya enviado nada con el metodo POST, no se realizará esta parte del código.
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        //se guardan los datos ingresados por el usuario en variables para su manipulación
        $usuario=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['usuario']);
        $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['password']);
        //$error='';
        //la contraseña se convierte en formato codificado sha1
        $sha1_pass=sha1($password);
        // se realiza la consulta a la BD con los datos ingresados
        $sql = "SELECT IdUsuario, IdTipo FROM Usuario WHERE Usuario = '$usuario' AND password='$sha1_pass'";
        //se obtienen los resultados de la consulta y cada uno de los campos
        $result = $conexion->query($sql); 
        $rows=$result->num_rows;
        // si los campos no estan vacios...
        if($rows >0){

            //se guardan los datos de usuario en la sesión actual y se redirecciona al menú del sistema
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['IdUsuario'];
            $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $row['IdTipo'];

            header ("location: extraescolares/home.php");
        }else{
            //$error = "El nombre o contrase&ntilde;a son incorrectos";
            //si los datos corroborados en la BD no existen, se redireccionará a la página principal sin acceso
            echo"<script>alert('El nombre de usuario o contraseña son incorrectos'); window.location.href=\"index.php\"</script>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Este es el otro código de la pagina una vez que debería de haber iniciado sesión

```
<?php
    //llamada a la conexion con la BD y la sesión
    require'../conexion/conexion.php';
    require'../operaciones/fecha.php';//Llamada a la funcion fecha
    session_start();

    // si no reconoce el inicio de sesion redirecciona a la pagina principal index.php
    if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
        header("location: ../index.php");
    }//si reconoce la sesion continua con la pagina 

    //guarda los datos del usuario que inició sesión
    $idusuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_SESSION['id_usuario']);
    $tipodeusuario=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_SESSION['tipo_usuario']);

    //TIempo de sesiòn del usuario
    //Variable que devuelve la hora actual
    $ahora = time();

    //realiza una consulta a la base de datos para devolver el tipo de usuario que ha iniciado sesión
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario AS u WHERE u.IdUsuario='$idusuario'";
    $result=$conexion->query($sql);
    $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
    $user=utf8_decode(utf8_encode($row['Nombres'])).' '.utf8_decode(utf8_encode($row['ApellidoP']));

    //Consulta a la BD para arrojar los datos de los usuarios del sistema
    $consulta="SELECT u.Nombres, u.ApellidoP, u.ApellidoM, u.Usuario, u.Password, t.Tipo FROM usuario AS u INNER JOIN tipousuario AS t ON t.IdTipo=u.IdTipo";
    $resulta=$conexion->query($consulta);
    $contador=0;

?>
```

Comment: podrias colocar en donde creas tus password o el hash de la base de datos? o puedes validar  el password dando un `echo $sha1_pass;` y `echo $row["password"];` de ese usuario de momento quitando el `AND password='$sha1_pass'` en la consulta!

Comment: oye amigo, te puedo pasar su cuenta ftp para que cheques el código?

Comment: lo probé pero aun no funciona, te puedo pasar el acceso ftp,

Comment: solo imprime y validad si son iguales de momento no se podria!

Comment: Puedes probar... $sql = "SELECT IdUsuario, IdTipo FROM Usuario WHERE Usuario = '".$usuario."' AND password='".$sha1_pass."'";

Comment: Hola gracias por contestar pero igual no funciona ya puse lo que escribise pero no jala, La verdad me gustaria que me ayudaras, te paso la cuenta ftp para que chekes el codigo, y te pueda depositar  una ayuda tu dime de cuanto $, la verdad necesito iniciar sesión este es mi correo petercam94@gmail.com